# Redraw widget with Delay in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to remove a content from a Widget based on a conditional logic.

Below is my Widget tree,

```
return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(120.0),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Loading...");
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
));
```

Lets say I have a variable which fetches value from SharePreferences and if the value is "Hide" then Text widget encapsulated inside must be hidden. Otherwise it should display the text fetched from the SP.

The catch here is that the Text will initially display "Loading..." for a specific duration and then after that it must behave dynamically based on the condition.

I have tried with `Timer` and `setState()` but couldn't really make it work. Kindly assist if anyone has a solution for this.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 20):

Jordan Davies is right. You need a `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder`.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(120.0),
        child: Center(
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
                builder: (c, s) => s.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                    ? Text("Loaded")
                    : Text("Loading..."))),
      ),
    ));
```

Just replace `Future.delayed` with your function.

Comment: Great example... like

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the solution finally which combines @olexa.le's `Future.Delayed` method along with a few modifications.

```
 main() {
    runApp(MyPrimaryWidgetBuilder());

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String appRunStatus = sharedPreferences.getString("appStartStatus");

    if( appRunStatus == null || appRunStatus == "" ){
        //Redraw new Widget
    }
}
```

Now my initial Widget will be drawn to the viewport and then the `main()` method will wait for 5 seconds due to the delay set in the `Future`. Then the conditional block will check the value returned by `sharedPreferences.getString()`

If the value is NULL then my goal is to draw a new widget replacing the existing one. Inside the conditional module, I just invoke the `runApp()` method again with a new widget.

```
if( appRunStatus == null || appRunStatus == "" ){
      runApp(
         new MaterialApp(
             home: Scaffold(
                 body: Container(
                    child: Text("You Are running the app for the first time..."),
                 ),
             ),
      );
}
```

Assume that, initially the layout displayed will hold the text ***"Loading..."*** and this will stay as such for 5 seconds. After 5 seconds based on the value returned by 
SharePreferences, the whole app's view will be redrawn with a new widget.

I have redrawn around 6 new widgets and also included a few animations based to suit my use case. The `Text` widget is just a sample and you can replace it with whatever you want and this will work. It will be suitable for redrawing widgets with new children without navigating to a new page.

This worked for me and if there is a better solution to achieve the same with more efficiency, then please do share that.